# pyCharm doesn't open plot with "Show plots in tool window" disabled - probably due to blocking

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, mne-python

I'm trying to plot an interactive plot with pyCharm (from mne), and disabled "Show plots in tool window". When I run my code, I see that a new window is trying to open, but closes immediately, as if something is blocking it. I know it's not a problem with the plot itself, as it works when "Show plots in tool window" is enabled (but than it's not interactive).
I have no idea what's blocking the new window, does someone have an idea?

I'm working on Mac (Big Sur).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve it by using `plt.show(block=True)` instead of `plt.show()`. This blocks the python script from finishing and closing the figure. Once you close the figure, the python script continues.